# PHP : How to echo return array method?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a class that has this method:

```
public function user_status()
    {    
            $json = //some code here...
            $result = json_decode($json, true);
            $status = array(
                'key1' => $val1,
                'key2' => $val2
            );
            return $status;

    }
```

when calling like this:

```
$user = new Class();
echo $user->user_status();
```

it just returns the word `Array`
but when dumping like so:

```
echo "<pre>User: ", print_r($user->user_status(), TRUE), "</pre>";
```

it prints the array as expected:

```
User: Array
(
    [key1] => val1
    [key2] => val2
)
```

I want to output the array values so I tried calling it like below but its giving me a parse error.

```
echo $user->user_status()->['key2'];
```

Whats the proper syntax to output the array values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 or older:

```
$array = $user->user_status();
echo $array['key2'];
```

In PHP 5.4 and newer:

```
echo $user->user_status()['key2'];
```

PHP 5.4 introduced array dereferencing which allows us to shorten the syntax a bit.

Comment: You have to echos! not sure why this has been down voted though

Comment: I tried the latter approach but its giving me a parse error. must be the php version.

Comment: +1 - I like this answer best. Clear and concise. I would add 5.4+ stuff to the top though :)

Comment: I like @zavg answer just because the variable naming is more clearer but I will choose this answer for completeness! thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
echo $user->user_status()['key2'];
```

The return value of user_status() itself is an array, so you can "treat the function call as if it would be the name of a variable".

Comment: yeah. tried that before but its giving me a parse error. I suspect its because my php version does not support it. but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

```
$status = $user->user_status();
echo $status['key2'];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax

```
$array = $user->user_status();

echo $array['key2'];
```